# Issue with formula output on if else statement. what can i do fix this?

Tags: c++

im taking my first CS class and we just went over if-else statements.
I can get the "if" part of the code to output what i want. but the else statement isnt out putting what i want. i would appreciate the help. Here are the inputs i used.
credit hours=21, lab courses=2, is the student in district: n

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


// main program
int main()
{
    // declarations
    int credHours, lab_courses;
    char answer;
    double tuition_cost, total_tuition, labCost;
    const double inTuition=70.00, outTuition=255.54, labFee=85.00;


    //enter credit hours
    cout<<"Enter the number of credit hours: ";
    cin>>credHours;

    //enter amount of lab courses
    cout<<"Enter the number of lab courses: ";
    cin>>lab_courses;

    //student is asked if they are in district
    cout<<"Is the student \"in district\" (y or n): ";
    cin>>answer;
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    if(answer=='y'||'Y')
    {
        tuition_cost=credHours*inTuition; //calculates the cost of in state tuition before lab fees(if they apply)
        cout<<"Tuition costs: "<<tuition_cost<<endl;
        if(lab_courses>0)
        {
            labCost=lab_courses*labFee;        //calculates lab fees
            cout<<"Lab fees: "<<labCost<<endl;
            total_tuition=labCost+tuition_cost; //calculates total in state tuition cost once lab fees are applied
        }
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(2);
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Your total payment is: "<<total_tuition<<endl; //outputs total tuition costs for in state students

    }
    else
    {
        tuition_cost=credHours*outTuition; //calculates the cost of out of state tuition before lab fees(if they apply)
        cout<<"Tuition costs: "<<tuition_cost<<endl;
        if(lab_courses>0)
        {
            labCost=lab_courses*labFee;         //calculates lab fees
            cout<<"Lab fees: "<<labCost<<endl;
            total_tuition=labCost+tuition_cost; //calculates total out state tuition cost once lab fees are applied
        }

        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(2);

        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Your total payment is: "<<total_tuition<<endl; //outputs total tuition costs for out of state students
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the else statement printing _instead of_ what you want? Nothing? Incorrect values?

Comment: First lesson: C != C++.  The code you show is strictly C++; do not dual tag with C.  You will merely annoy people, and annoyed people are apt to cast downvotes.

Comment: `if(answer=='y'||'Y')` this does not do what you think it does, what you want is `if(answer=='y'|| answer == 'Y')`.

Comment: the else statement is giving incorrect values. for tuition cost it outputs 1470 when it should be 5366.34. It is outputting the correct value for lab fees though. The if statement is outputting the correct values for me as well.

Comment: I believe the `if` statement will always be true since 'Y' is a character with a positive ASCII value and you've just it it there with no condition, so since anything non-zero is true, 'Y' will always make the if statement true. Do as @Borgleader said and change it.

Comment: Aren't the lab fees `0` anyway? You said your input is `lab courses=0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in here as said by @Borgleader

```
if(answer=='y'||'Y')
```

what's is basically doing is expanding to something like this

```
 if((static_cast<int>(answer) == static_cast<int>('y')) || static_cast<bool>('Y'))
```

if you see this expression will always evaluate to true , so your else part is never called .

when you do

```
 if(answer=='y'|| answer=='Y')
```

compiler will evaluate it to something like

```
 if((static_cast<int>(answer) == static_cast<int>('y')) || (static_cast<int>(answer) == static_cast<int>('Y'))) {
```

which you want to do if I am right .